# Navbar contents, icons, and card body? (HTML, bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have 3 issues:

1. The contents of my navbar after the navbar-brand area will not show up for some reason. I am trying to add a home button, about section with a drop-down menu containing: 'Our mission', 'our team', 'faq;' a contact button, etc. (see picture for reference)
   [image]
2. The icon in my card footers will not appear
3. How do I make the gray part of the cards a transparent gray color that also shows the body background?

   ```
   <head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app3.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


     <title>Quarantine Blog</title>
   </head>

   <body>
     <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark">
       <div class="container">
         <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Quarantine Pal</a>
       </div>

       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
           <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
             <li class="nav-item active">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
             </li>
             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                 <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                   About
                 </a>
                 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Mission</a>
                   <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Team</a>
                   <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">FAQ</a>
                 </div>
                 <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Our Founder</a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Press</a></li>

               </ul>

               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li><a href="#">Sign Up  <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Login   <i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>

                 </li>
               </ul>
             </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
           </div>

     </nav>

     <section id="header" class="jumbotron text-center">
       <h1 class="display-3">Quarantine State of Mind</h1>
       <p class="lead">Exploring the 'New Normal'</p>
       <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</a>
       <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Login</a>
     </section>

     <div class="container">
     <div class="card-deck">
       <div class="card">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588776409240-05d32e7614f5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80" class="card-img-top" alt="Sailor Moon">
         <div class="card-body">
           <h5 class="card-title text-center">Self-Care and Burn Out</h5>
           <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
           <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-footer">
           <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-sm">Download</a>
           <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588779851655-558c2897779d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80" class="card-img-top" alt="Inuyasha">
         <div class="card-body">
           <h5 class="card-title text-center">Help Fight Coronavirus</h5>
           <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
           <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-footer">
           <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-sm">Download</a>
           <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588777308282-b3dd5ce9fb67?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80" class="card-img-top" alt="Dragon Ball Z">
         <div class="card-body">
           <h5 class="card-title text-center">Pandemic Socializing</h5>
           <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
           <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-footer">
           <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-sm">Download</a>
           <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>
     </div>


     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   </body>

   </html>
   ```

CSS:

```
#header {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: center bottom;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-brand {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.bg-dark.navbar-dark {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

body {
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588774210246-a1dc467758df?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1934&q=80') 

}

.card-body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',
}

.lead {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.card-body {
    background-color: gray; 
    opacity: 80%;
}

.card-title {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.card-text {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: It is better to post 1 question or problem one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have fixed your navigation issue. You may need to change the style of the navigation items.
2. I also fix your icon display issue, you need to use Font Awesome 4 style. `fa fa-heart-o`
   [image][image]
3. Finally, I also add in CSS code to make the background of the card body becomes 80% transparent. Class `.card` background-color need to set to transparent and class `card-footer` background-color need to set to white.

```
.card {
  background-color: transparent !important; 
}
.card-body {
    background-color: gray; 
    opacity: 80%;
}
.card-footer {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

```css
#header {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: center bottom;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-brand {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.bg-dark.navbar-dark {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

body {
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588774210246-a1dc467758df?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1934&q=80') 

}

.card-body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',
}

.lead {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
.card {
  background-color: transparent !important; 
}
.card-body {
    background-color: gray; 
    opacity: 80%;
}
.card-footer {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
.card-title {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.card-text {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- <div class="container" style="background: yellow;"> -->
  <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Quarantine Pal</a>
  <!-- </div> -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                About
              </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Mission</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Team</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">FAQ</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Our Founder</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Press</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up  <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Login   <i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  <!-- </div> -->

</nav>

<section id="header" class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1 class="display-3">Quarantine State of Mind</h1>
  <p class="lead">Exploring the 'New Normal'</p>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</a>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Login</a>
</section>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588776409240-05d32e7614f5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80" class="card-img-top" alt="Sailor Moon">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Self-Care and Burn Out</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-sm">Download</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588779851655-558c2897779d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80" class="card-img-top" alt="Inuyasha">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Help Fight Coronavirus</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-sm">Download</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588777308282-b3dd5ce9fb67?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80" class="card-img-top" alt="Dragon Ball Z">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Pandemic Socializing</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-sm">Download</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```